# Why OLED TVs are not smaller than 55 inch?

Tags: oled

Why OLED TVs are not smaller than 55 inch? Are there any techincal issues or just marketing/revenue problems? I saw OLEDs in operation - and was impressed - the quality perhaps even beter than of plasma TVs (LCDs are garbage compared to OLEDs). I would prefer 37...42 inch OLED TV, but such sizes are not available..

Comment: To legitimize the higher price I think. Fewer would buy a very expensive small TV.

Comment: I'd guess that it has to do with making profit. It's smart business to go after the high-end dollars first while you shake out a product that might attract the attention of such buyers with unique features. You have fewer customers, which means significantly fewer support calls and you can provide better after-sale support and service, while still making good money. It's expensive to field, either way, so you are MUCH better off providing what wealthy buyers want -- big screens, better pictures -- and focusing attention there. Later, as production volume rises, you can migrate downward.

Answer (score 2):

No technical issue with small OLED screens, there are some smartphones and tablets with OLED screens, much smaller than 55".

Comment: Even the Apple Watch [reportedly uses an OLED screen](https://www.oled-info.com/confirmed-apples-watch-uses-amoled-display).